# Move the read files along with same named different format files

Tags: python, python-2.7, fits

I have a file that contains lots of .fits and .dat files. First, I want them separated by a parameter and moved to another file(I have this part done). Then, the problem is there is a .dat file with exact same name for each .fits file (for example  kkk.fits , kkk_trl.dat ) and I want the same named .dat file to move along with the .fits file together to the new folder.

```
 import os
 import glob
 import pyfits
 import shutil


for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
hdu = hdulist[0]
a = hdulist[0].header['OBJECT']
if a == "Bach":
shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/Bach/')
   b == a + '.dat'
    shutil.move(b, '/home/Bach/')
```

With this code I am able to move all the .fits files with ease but .dat files remains.

The code below is close to the answer but gives another problem that this time the code tries to move a file named kkk.fits.dat with the last line. I need it to read the file as kkk_trl.dat

```
import os
import glob
import pyfits
import shutil


for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
hdu = hdulist[0]
a = hdulist[0].header['OBJECT']
if a == "Bach":
shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/Bach/')
shutil.move((fitsName +'*.dat') , '/home/Bach/')
```

Latest step taken towards to the solution is below. This time code gives no error but only the .fits file goes to the destination folder and .dat file stays there.

```
import os
import glob
import pyfits
import shutil


for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
hdu = hdulist[0]
a = hdulist[0].header['OBJECT']
if a == "Bach":
shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/Bach/')
b = os.path.splitext(fitsName[0]) + '_trl.dat'
shutil.move(b, '/home/Bach/')
```

Comment: that is because your a is bach or chopin etc. so you need to take the name with extension.

Comment: No that is the parameter name on the file, like that this code works and the items on a moves to the corresponding folder without problem. Problem is the files corresponding to b is not moving..

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: As @MarkTolonen wrote, when asking for help with Python code it is very important to retain the correct indentation of your original code.  Please edit your post to correct the indentation so that we can see what lines are inside the `for` loop, for example.  In some cases the intent is obvious but in this case it really isn't clear until/unless you fix the indentation.

Comment: it is all inside the for loop. For each .fits file there is an equivelent .dat file so the cycle goes until each same named fits and dat files are moved. Right now with this code all the fits files move but dat files stay where they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line

```
shutil.move((fitsName +'*.dat'), '/home/Bach/')`
```

the variable `fitsName` is a string looking like `something.fits`.  Now you're appending to it the string `'*.dat'` to create the string `something.fits*.dat` literally. This means move the file the is *literally* named `something.fits*.dat`, which presumably does not exist.  You probably want something like `os.path.splitext(fitsName[0]) + '.dat'`.

Note also that wildcard expansions like with `*` are not generally meaningful to functions in Python that accept filenames.  Wildcard expansion is a feature of your *shell* (e.g. the command line).  In fact that's the reason you have to use the `glob` module to get functionality like this in Python.  `glob.glob('*.foo')` is similar to doing `ls *.foo` in your shell but you have to use the `glob` module directly for that functionality.  In general if you pass a filename containing `*` to a function (e.g. like `shutil.move`, which despite being in the "shell utils" module does *not* support wildcard expansion) it will just treat is as a literal `*`.

Please see also my general tips for debugging simple Python programs at [My python code that converts numbers between bases has several errors. What could be wrong and how can I find them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353953/my-python-code-that-converts-numbers-between-bases-has-several-errors-what-coul/52354973#52354973)

Comment: Thank you very much, I accept this because the slightly different code : os.path.splitext(fitsName)[0] + '.dat' is actually worked! Thanks for the references as well!

Answer (score 1):

### Assignment vs comparison

The statement `b == a + '.dat'` is equal to False and does not assign anything to `b` like `b = a + '.dat'` would.

Comment: That also does not work. Problem is when I call the unit a, its name is kkk.fits and when I say a + '.dat' to b, it actually tries to move a file named kkk.fits.dat , how can I make it only read as kkk.dat is my problem

Comment: @NapolyoN the code you provide doesn't fit what you're asking. Please ensure that you're posting *exact* code that you've tested that produces the particular symptoms.

Comment: thank you, just added my next step to the fix to the question at the bottom.