# moving multiple files by a parameter applied beforehand

Tags: python, file, move, shutil, fits

I have problem moving a dependent file. I have lots of files with 2 different exts. For example ; xenian10.fits, xenian11.fits, xenian12.fits and for each there is an equilevant version with different ext like xenian10.no, xenian11.no, xenian12.no and so on.

All the .fits files contain a different parameter so it's something like this;

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import pyfits

for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    hdu = hdulist[0]
    a= hdulist[0].header['ITEM']
    if a == "color":
        shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/color/')
    b = os.path.splitext(fitsName)[O] + '.no'
    shutil.move(b, '/home/color/')
    if a == "smell":
        shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/smell/')
    b = os.path.splitext(fitsName)[O] + '.no'
    shutil.move(b, '/home/smell/')
```

The problem here is for the first line that contains the splitex;

```
b = os.path.splitex(fitsName)[O] + '.no'
shutil.move(b, '/home/color/')
```

moves all the files with .no ext files. However, I want it to be only linked to the .fits files that were moved to by the"color" parameter from the previous line of the code only. Because currently if only xenian10.fits is with the parameter "color" among all others, then only the corresponding .fits file moves, so that part is ok, but after that I want only xenian10.no file to move, however the code moves all of the .no files inside folder disregarding that the only .fits moved was xenian10.fits.

Comment: You need to indent the `.no` copying code so that it is in the `if a == "color:"` block and similarly for the smell block.

Comment: this is the actual code, sorry I did not copy paste but wrote by hand, missed the : so I fixed it now. However code takes every .no files away..

Comment: If this were the actual code you are running you would be getting an `AttributeError` because the function you're trying to use is spelled [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).  Is there a reason you can't copy/paste it?

Comment: Weirdly I just answered an almost identical question also involving FITS files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476516/move-the-read-files-along-with-same-named-different-format-files

Comment: @Iguananaut I just checked the question you have answered. It's a similar situation but I need the files moved by a parameter as I have stated. Currently, with this code and your answer to that question takes all the files away to the directory. I would like to move the same named .no files to be moved along with .fits files.

Comment: I just don't understand what's going on that that code is almost exactly identical.  Did it come from like a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was only with indentation.

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import pyfits

for fitsName in glob.glob('*.fits'):
    hdulist = pyfits.open(fitsName)
    hdu = hdulist[0]
    a= hdulist[0].header['ITEM']
    if a == "color":
        shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/color/')
        b = os.path.splitext(fitsName)[O] + '.no'
        shutil.move(b, '/home/color/')
    if a == "smell":
        shutil.move(fitsName, '/home/smell/')
        b = os.path.splitext(fitsName)[O] + '.no'
        shutil.move(b, '/home/smell/')
```