# Python append acting funny

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a python code, to solve a puzzle. It was not working as expected. So while debugging I saw something very weird. Row is a list of lists. The append 1 to single `row[n]` appends to all lists inside row!

```
def trap( height):
        row = []

        for index, i in enumerate(height):
            if i == 0 and len(row) == 0:
                continue
            else:
                if(i > len(row)):#time for a new row
                  #to old rows append 0 below  
                  for j in range(0, len(row)):
                        row[j].append(0)
                  row = row + [[0]] * (i - len(row))            
                else:
                  for j in range(0,i):
                     row[j].append(0)
                  #PROBLEMATIC CODE START  
                  for jo in range(i,len(row)):
                        if(index == 1):
                            print("jays are",row)
                            print("jo is",jo, row[jo])
                        row[jo].append(1)
                  #PROBLEMATIC CODE END (I GUESS?)


        print(row) #print this, it gives an idea


trap([2,0])
```

When I try this independently, it works fine, see:

```
row = [[0],[0]]
index = 1

for jo in range(0,len(row)):
      if(index == 1):
                  print("jays are",row)
                  print("jo is",jo, row[jo])
                  row[jo].append(1)
print(row)
```

The problematic code has been marked in the python as comment `#PROBLEMATIC CODE START` and `#PROBLEMATIC CODE END`. Call the `trap()` with `[2,0]`

row variable should be `[[0,1],[0,1]]`
but row variable is coming `[[0,1,1],[0,1,1]]`

I have been at this for many hours! I just don't understand why does `.append()` appends to all the lists inside row, but when I try the smaller code it works. Please help me and guide me

Comment: The problem is the way you edited the row.  **row = row + [[0]] * (i - len(row))** when using the " * " operator with list, the same object gets to be referenced several times along the row.

Comment: Pretty sure `list.append` is working normally and your code is just confused :)  You might find my [general tips on debugging small Python programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353953/my-python-code-that-converts-numbers-between-bases-has-several-errors-what-coul/52354973#52354973)  helpful.  In general, start from the code that *was* working, and build on it a bit at a time, making sure that each step works as you expect, rather than try to do everything at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating a list using `*`, you are just copying the reference to the object and not the instance itself. Short example:

```
>>> a = [["abv"]] * 3
>>> a
[['abv'], ['abv'], ['abv']]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[['abv', 1], ['abv', 1], ['abv', 1]]
```

I'm creating a list which contains the object `["abv"]` 3 times. It's all the same object, just 3 times in the list.
As soon as I edit one item, it looks like all items are updated but actually it's all the same.

You'd need to create your list like this to create a new object for every iteration:

```
>>> a = [["abv"] for _ in range(3)]
```

So your code should be changed to this:

```
row += [[0] for x in range(i - len(row))]
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer this question, you would need to modify your code a little bit.

```
#to old rows append 0 below  
for j in range(0, len(row)):
    row[j].append(0)
row = row + [[0]] * (i - len(row))
```

You need to modify it to remove the multiple reference on the same object.

```
#to old rows append 0 below  
for j in range(0, len(row)):
    row[j].append(0)
row += [[0] for x in range(i - len(row))]
```

with this, you should probably get the correct values.